# How to check if database was successfully restored using the dump file?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script to get a dump from a 2GB **mysql** database. I am then deleting this database and I restore this database from the bash script using the mysql dump. I will initiate this script from a remote machine. So I need a way of finding out if the dump restoring process finished in the remote machine to execute the next commands. As I couldn't find anything online I tried to see if the made databse size was equal to the desiresd database size. Even this, I am not able to do as I used the below script to get the database size:

```
size=$(mysql -u root -ppass -D tpcw -e "SELECT  sum(round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024), 2))  as 'Size in GB' FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'tpcw'")
```

and when I try to run this script:

```
    size=$(mysql -u root -ppass -D tpcw -e "SELECT  sum(round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024), 2))  as 'Size in GB' FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'tpcw'")

    echo $size

    if [ "$size" == "Size in GB 2.47" ] ; then
        echo "match"
        break 
    else
        echo "does not match"
    fi
```

It returns "does not match". This is beause the string retuned by the query shows as

> Size in GB
>   2.47

when I print it using:

```
echo "$size"
```

But it prints like:

> Size in GB 2.47

when I print it using:

```
echo $size
```

I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: `echo` ignores line break characters like `\n` in a string. https://superuser.com/questions/256465/echo-newline-character-not-working-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed a newline in your test string:

```
 if [ "$size" = "Size in GB"$'\n'"2.47" ] ; then
```

> I can't figure out what is wrong.

The `size` variable has a newline inside it. When you do

```
 echo "$size"
```

It is executed as:

```
 echo $'Size in GB\n2.47'
```

The newline get's printed out, the spaces get's preserved, and echo get's only one argument.

When you do:

```
 echo $size
```

Then it executes echo with 4 arguments:

```
 echo 'Size' 'in' 'GB' '2.47'
```

And echo prints them separating with a space. Argument splitting is done on spaces, newline and tabulations (for default IFS).

> How to check if database was successfully restored using the dump file?

Just check mysql exit status when restoring the database.

```
if ! mysql -u root -ppass <dump.file; then
    echo "Och no, restoring the database failed!"
fi
```

or

```
mysql -u root -ppass <dump.file
ret=$?
if (($ret != 0)); then
    echo "Och no, restoring the database failed with exit status $ret!"
fi
```